# Download full anaconda distribution in a new environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using the Anaconda python 2.x distribution.
I wanted to have python 3 installed, keeping python 2.

I used the conda environment feature:

```
conda create --name py3 python=3
```

That worked great, and I am able to switch between the two seamlessly.

The problem is that on my python3 install I don't have all the packages that the anaconda distribution comes with (such as numpy, pandas, the continuum analytics ones..)

Is there an easy way to get them all from the command line?

Comment: read https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: short: activate the environment and install your required packages

Comment: I read that already, I don't think it has the answer to that specific question. I know that I can do `conda install package_name` for each of them, my question was if there was a way to install all the ones coming with the full distribution at once, which would be much less tedious

Comment: I have the same question. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

This is like installing the Anaconda meta-package as an environment. You need to run the following:

```
conda create --name ENV_NAME PYTHON_VERSION anaconda
```

For example: If you want to make a environment named `myEnv` with python version 3.5 and full Anaconda distribution, you would run;

```
conda create --name myEnv python=3.5 anaconda
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your virtual environment run:

```
conda install anaconda
```

I hope it helps!

As I get it, the feature is available only from Anaconda Promt, no way of installing anaconda by `pip install` command. For possible proof read the description of this package:
https://pypi.org/project/anaconda/